# implementing remember my username/password feature

Tags: asp.net

I'm going to implement a "REMEMBER my username and password" feature for my login page, how should I do that? what are the steps required? I use ASP.NET,C#,VS2010, of course I've not used ASP.NET built-in membership features, rather I've used sessions and query string to authenticate my users, of course my login page works fine and now I'm going to add a remember me feature
is there any sample or tutorial?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cookie based Forms Authentication, you need to create a persistent cookie when user clicks on remember me check box - this is a parameter to [FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.setauthcookie.aspx) or [FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka5ffkce.aspx) methods.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
protected void btnSignIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("TimeOut");
            cookie["IsLoged"] = "true";
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(userEmail, cbxRememberMe.Checked);
        }
```

You can find more detaiols here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka5ffkce(v=VS.90).aspx